# Box Sizing unformat entire page

Tags: php, html, css

It may be a question a bit silly, but for those who have little experience in css like me is not so easy. The thing is I'm trying to implement a login exemple in my project. Of course you need to configure the css, paths, etc..

The problem is that configure the login panel that has the following instructions:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This makes all the boxes in every application that has become disfigured. How can I resolve this? I tried to name the div where it is called and changed the name to `*` this div. But nothing doing. Someone can help me?

```
echo '<div class="container">           
            <section class="main">
            <form class="form-1" id="login" method="post">
            <p class="field">
                <input type="text" name="login" id="username" placeholder="Nº Funcionario">
                <i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>
            </p>
                <p class="field">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Senha">
                <i class="icon-lock icon-large"></i>
            </p>
            <p class="submit">
                <button type="submit" value="Login" id="loginme" name="submit">
                <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-large"></i></button>
            </p>
            </form>
            </section></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use border box.

Default, the width of elements is calculated like this:

width = set width propperty + padding + border width

border box, means width is calculated differently, there are also other propperties for box sizing like padding-box.

tldr remove all this, it was most likely included by someone looking for a quick and ugly fix to a particular problem.

Also box-sizing isnt supported in many browsers, but width is supported in all browsers. You are bound to have major problems using it.

Comment: But once the login panel is unformatted. What solution do I have? Example I want to use is the following: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomLoginFormStyling/index.html is the demo 1

Comment: Paul Irish says its totally cool:  http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Citing the page you linked "Due to browser support, this recommendation is only for projects that support IE8 and up." using this can TOTALLY break layout in say IE7. Not cool for real production.

Comment: And IE7 has quirks mode, which *does* use the "wrong" box model.  I've dropped support for IE7 in my work.

Comment: if you dont know much about css and dont have much experiance its a lot better to learn the basics first instead open pandoras box, which is quirksmode. Not sure what "work" you do if ou dont know that...

Comment: My work and devenvolver a system to manage activities and virtually ja ta all done. So I wanted to better my login window to become funny to you. I have already put the code, I am using html. I have some knowledge of CSS, but I'm no expert dai have come to ask for help

Comment: if you are not an expert, copy paste the examples 1 to 1! just keep in mind its not super cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

If the widths of all of your elements has been calculated using the standard box model, you can't just drop this on top of it.  Both `*` and `div` cover a lot of elements.  If you need `box-sizing: border-box` for one element, then only specify it for that element:

```
div.foo,
div.foo:after,
div.foo:before {
    /* ... */
}
```